# Fetch sharepoint list data into python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint, azure-databricks

i have created a list in sharepoint-> my lists. Following is the URL

```py
url = 'https://xxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/account@******.com/Lists/MySamplelist/AllItems.aspx?env=WebViewList'

username = 'account@*****.com'
password = 'pwd'

cred = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)
site = Site(url, auth=cred, verify_ssl=False)
```

While trying to load data from sharepoint using above URL through site() I am getting error as below

```
ShareplumRequestError: Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: 
'https://xxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/account@******.com/Lists/MySamplelist/AllItems.aspx?env=WebViewList'
```

Please let me know what canI do to get rid of the error and load the sharepoint list data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, **SharePoint** is not supported in **Azure Databricks**.

> **Any alternative options ?**

Yes, there are couple of **alternative options** to read share point files in **Azure Databricks**.

**Option 1**: Transfer files from SharePoint to Blob storage with azure [**logic apps**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5893/transfer-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-with-azure-logic-apps/), then mount the storage account to Azure Databricks and read data from storage account.

**Option 2**: Copy files from SharePoint into Azure blob storage using [**Azure Data Factory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online).

You can refer this [**document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#--mount-an-azure-blob-storage-container) to learn more about Mount an Azure Blob storage container to Azure Databricks.